# NLTK parse complex list into tree

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to parse a list returned from a [max entropy syntactic parser](https://github.com/emilmont/pyStatParser) into a nltk tree but from what i see [here](http://www.monlp.com/2011/12/16/nltk-trees/) the tree is created by initialising every single node, is there an easier way to do that?
This is a list example.

```
[u'SBAR', [u'WHADVP+WRB', 'how'], [u'S', [u'VP', [u'VBD', 'did'], [u'VP', [u'VB', 'serfdom'], [u'VP', [u'VB', 'develop'], [u'SBAR', [u'IN', 'in'], [u'S', [u'CC', 'and'], [u'S', [u'ADVP+RB', 'then'], [u'VP', [u'VB', 'leave'], [u'NP+NNP', 'Russia']]]]]]]], [u'.', '?']]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following function for a recursive solution to the above.

```
def List_To_Tree(lst):
    if(not isinstance(lst, basestring)):
        if(len(lst) == 2 and isinstance(lst[0], basestring) and isinstance(lst[1], basestring)):                
            lst = Tree(str(lst[0]).split('+')[0],[str(lst[1])])
        elif(isinstance(lst[0], basestring) and not isinstance(lst[1], basestring)):
            lst = Tree(str(lst[0]).split('+')[0],map(List_To_Tree, lst[1: len(lst) ]))
    return lst
```